# How to solve the "integer division by zero" problem during the application of opencv?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, exception

When I use OpenCV in the visual studio with C++ to process an image, it occurs this Exception unhandled problem as follows:
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF81406F880 (opencv_world455d.dll) in ImageFilterTest.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.

my source code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // read image
    Mat image = imread("../Images/im092002.jpg");
    
    //print error message if image is null
    if (image.empty())
    {
        cout << "Could not read image" << endl;
    }
    //apply identiy filter using kernel
    Mat kernel1 = (Mat_<double>(5, 5) << 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Mat identity;
    filter2D(image, identity, -1, kernel1, Point(-1, -1), 0, 4);
    imshow("Orginal", image);
    imshow("Identity", identity);
    destroyAllWindows();

    //blurred using kernel
    //initalize matrix with all ones
    Mat kernel2 = Mat::ones(5, 5,CV_64F);
    kernel2 = kernel2 / 25;
    Mat img;
    filter2D(image, img, -1, kernel2, Point(-1, -1), 0, 4);
    imshow("Original", image);
    imshow("kernel blur", img);
    imwrite("blur_kernel.jpg", img);
    waitKey();
    destroyAllWindows();

}
```

I have no basis at all to this kind of problem, can any one tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well I'm in the same boat as you. But the first step would be to use your debugger to find out exactly which line of your code is causing the division by zero. When you've found that out, edit the question above with that information.

Comment: how many elements should be in `Mat_<double>(5, 5)` ?  ;)

Comment: A 5x5 identity kernel doesn't seem more useful than 3x3 (as your numbers suggest that you intended).

Comment: The dividend cannot be zero, so a non-zero judgment must be made when using division.

Comment: the last 16 coeffs in your kernel were never initialized properly